# How to remove a specific range of characters from a text file?

Tags: csv, text, notepad++

I have a txt file (opened in notepad++) in the form of:

```
Name|Address|City|St|Zip|Off|Z|Contact|Telephone|800|Fax|Notes
```

My problem is that when the file was exported there was multiple pages and now I have:

```
Page 1 of 134
Locations
3/3/2015
 |Name|Address|City|St|Zip|Off|Z|Contact|Telephone|800|Fax|Notes
```

in throughout the file. I am removing them manually, which takes time and I wanted to know if there is an easier way to do this?

Comment: I tried modifying this:
`(\+.*)(Item) \+ finds the + character. | .* selects the text after the + up until the word "Item" | Item finds the string "Item" | () allow us to access whatever is inside the parentheses. The first set of parentheses may be accessed with \1 and the second set with \2.`

Comment: Ok. What I ended up doing is using what @LocEngineer suggested which would get rid of the part of the text. Then I removed the `Name|Address|City|St|Zip|Off|Z|Contact|Telephone|800|Fax|Notes` and then I got rid of the empty lines using `\n\r` in extended mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad++ can do regex search/replace.
Use this search pattern (make sure to check the Regular expression" radio button:

Page [0-9]+? of [0-9]+?[\r\n\s\w\d/]+?\|

And replace with nothing.

Comment: That selected it up to
`Page 2 of 134
Locations
3/3/2015
 |`
Can you explain how it works so I can have it select up to "Notes"? It's a bit over my head, I haven't used regex  at all

Comment: Yeah. My bad: 1) it does select it up to the pipe char before notes. Replace with a single pipe char |.
If you "Replace All", it should remove all those lines at once.

Comment: Thanks mate. What do you mean with Replace with a single pipe char | ? I ended up sorting it out but I would like to understand it better.

Comment: The straight bar thing that separates your column names (|Name|Address|City|...) is called a pipe. Since the search pattern matches everything including the first pipe, replacing with nothing would remove the pipe before "Name". I thought you might not want that so I said put the pattern in the search field and one pipe in the replace field. That removes the junk but leaves the |Name|... line intact.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a find-and-replace operation based on a regular expression. For example, the regular expression '^Locations$' will match a line that begins and ends with the word "Locations". Replace the various regexps with an empty string.

An easier way is if you have access to a unix "grep" utility, you could pipe the file through it like this:

```
cat file.txt | grep -v '^Locations$' | grep -v '^Page [0-9]* of 134$' | grep -v '^[0-9]*/[0-9]*/[0-9]*$' > clean-file.txt
```

The '-v' argument means to not display any line that matches the regular expression.